# equivalent date from GNU to solaris

Tags: linux, bash, date, solaris

In `GNU` with the command date I can do it:

```
date -d "+4 day"


datei=20130101
i=5
date -d "$datei +$i day"
```

But i like know:

how can i do it in Solaris?

with the date command

Comment: Depending on the Solaris version and what packages the local admin has installed, GNU date may be available in `/usr/gnu/bin/date`, or as `gdate` in a directory such as `/usr/sfw/bin`, `/opt/csw/bin/`, `/usr/local/bin/`, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tcl has a good free-form date scanner, if you have Tcl installed (try `which tclsh`). A shell function:

```
tcldate() {
    d=${1:-now}   # the date string
    f=${2:-%c}    # the output format
    echo "puts [clock format [clock scan {$d}] -format {$f}]" | tclsh
}
```

In action on an ancient Solaris 8 box with bash 2.03 and tcl 8.3.3

```
$ tcldate
Tue Jul 23 13:27:17 2013
$ i=4
$ tcldate "$i days"
Sat Jul 27 13:27:34 2013
$ tcldate "$i days" "%Y-%m-%d"
2013-07-27
$ tcldate "20130101 + $i days" "%Y-%m-%d"
2013-01-05
```

This even handles daylight savings transitions:

```
$ tcldate "2014-03-09 00:30 + 1 hour" "%D %T %Z"
03/09/14 01:30:00 EST
$ tcldate "2014-03-09 00:30 + 2 hour" "%D %T %Z"
03/09/14 03:30:00 EDT
$ tcldate "2013-11-03 00:30 + 1 hour" "%D %T %Z"
11/03/13 01:30:00 EDT
$ tcldate "2013-11-03 00:30 + 2 hour" "%D %T %Z"
11/03/13 01:30:00 EST
```

Comment: i do not have tclsh. is there other way?

Comment: What does this give you: `perl -MDate::Manip -e 1` give you?

Comment: say me Can't locate Date/Manip.pm in @INC

Comment: I have very much problems, you have other idea?

Comment: You can install any perl module in your home directory without the need for elevated permission. I'd recommend that route.

Comment: I am intenting with a command perl: `perl -e '@T=localtime(time-86400);printf("%02d/%02d/%02d",$T[4]+1,$T[3],$T[5]+1900)'`

Comment: But i need do it with a variable for example  `i=2505600` and later, `perl -e '@T=localtime(time-$i);printf("%02d/%02d/%02d",$T[4]+1,$T[3],$T[5]+1900)'`