# AIX equivalent for 'date --date'

Tags: shell, date, aix

I frequently use the date command with the --date option on linux servers like

```
date --date="3min"
```

However the -d/--date option don't seems available on AIX server :
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_61/com.ibm.aix.cmds2/date.htm

Is it possible, and how can we get the same result as the following command:

```
date --utc --date "now $TIMEDELTA" +"%Y%m%d-%H")`
```

in an AIX environment ?

I don't have, and can't have, any root access to the server.

Comment: I guess this is the same problem that Solaris faces. You need to use Perl or another tool to process the data. See [equivalent date from GNU to solaris](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17815327/1983854).

Comment: The [Super User](http://superuser.com/) site is the better place to ask.

Answer (score 2):

A few options come to mind:

1. Download [`GNU date`](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/coreutils/) to your home directory and compile there. Pros: you get the full power of GNU date, with Cons: requires compilation and management, not immediately available to other users or machines.
2. Emulate the behavior using PERL, TCL, PHP, MySQL or any other high level language. Pros: you get a lot of power, without having to install anything, but with Cons: you have to know the language and you're dependent on it being there.
3. Use a shell based solution, like [`datecalc`](http://www.unix.com/unix-for-dummies-questions-and-answers/4870-days-elapsed-between-2-dates.html#post16559). If your `$TIMEDELTA` is in days, you could use: `datecalc $(date +'%Y %m %d') + $TIMEDELTA`. Pros: no external tools needed, with Cons: only works on day level granularity and isn't immediately available to other users or machines.
4. Purpose build your own little program using `strptime`, `getdate`, or other  C built-ins. Pros: decidedly solves *your* problem, with Cons: not immediately available to other users or machines, you might have to learn C, not forward flexible.