# Date arithmetic on AIX with no access to GNU date

Tags: bash, date, aix

Could you please help me in fetching the correct result for days addition to current date.

```
app503l:datechecker ~ $ date
Thu May 18 13:54:41 AEST 2017
```

How can I add 55 days to it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37029699/aix-equivalent-for-date-date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution..!

```
a=55
export a
perl -e 'use POSIX qw(strftime); print strftime "%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Y",localtime(time()+ 3600*24*$ENV{a});'
```

I have used perl to add 55 days to the current local time on the server.

Thanks..!

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
now=$(date +%s)
new=$((now + 55*86400))
date -r $new
```

With GNU date:

```
date -d @$new
```

Comment: -r is not recognized by my AIX..!
`date: Not a recognized flag: r`
`Usage: date [-u] [+"Field Descriptors"]`

Comment: How about `date -d @$new`?

Comment: Download GNU date and use `date -d @$new`.

Comment: Install busybox?

Comment: GNU is not enabled.

Comment: with gnu date `date -d "55 days"` is all that's needed.   but gnu date seems unavailable in this problem.