# How can we list all files of a directory before a particular day in Unix?

Tags: unix

How can we list all files of a directory created **before a particular day** in Unix?

Comment: Hi Arman welcome to SO, your question should show us the research efforts, and if any, the code you tried.

Comment: try this http://superuser.com/questions/560598/how-list-file-by-range-of-date

Answer (score 0):

If this may help, after you calculate the number of days between this particular day and today (It's not easy to do, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17817087/6019417) could be of help), then you can use `find -ctime -n`  where `n` is the number of days since the files where created.

```
find <your-directory> -ctime -5
```